# Billing stripe in salesforce app

Tags: salesforce, stripe-payments, visualforce, billing

I'm releasing an salesforce app and inside the app i want that the user will be able to
pay a total price according to things he purchased inside the app.
The total billing changes inside the app dynamically.

I understand that there is a billing mechanism called stripe but i dont understand how to open it from inside a visualforce page after a button click and how to change the payment amount dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

this is something i'm about to start looking although not from within an app - have you seen the SDK:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/recurring-billing-with-the-stripe-sdk-for-salesforce.html

this blog although not exactly what your after should get your started in the right direction.